# Was Visual Basic .NET omitted in survey questions?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

I missed doing the developer survey this year, I only saw its results. I can't see VB.NET anywhere in them. Recently, this language reaches new heights (5th place, 2 above the JavaScript) in the [TIOBE Index](https://tiobe.com/tiobe-index/).

How do you understand this?

Comment: Do use an accurate index: http://pypl.github.io/PYPL.html

Comment: @HansPassant It's unclear whether that list would be any more "accurate", just different. Measuring the number of times people search for tutorials would probably under-represent a language like VB.NET whose developers have probably been working with it for a long time, and have a large catalogue of non-web resources.

Comment: @HansPassant – I know that perceived accuracy issue, but still... Is this the inaccurately high entry in the TIOBE which is so unused, that it did not make it into SO survey?

Comment: There's just no point in flogging a dead horse.  I know it is unwelcome news to you, but take it from the top answerer in the [vb.net] tag: if your professional career needs to last another 10+ years then you need to learn new skills.  Consider yourself a victim of Tiobe's April 1st joke, albeit that it got started ten years ago.

Comment: I always know an index is accurate when the letters P and Y are used throughout the URL, and PYthon is rated the highest :P.

Comment: @HansPassant – I do not actively use that language. But there is a lot of confusion about it. Tiobe almost never comments it,  PYPL does not even recognize it (apart from "Visual Basic" umbrella term) and many developers think that VB6, VBA and VB.NET are the same language and technology. Barely someone notices that in some VB v12, the features were almost richer than the ones of C# and C# adopted many of them from there to be where it is now. I may be wrong, but I perceive VB.NET as underestimated gem. It's basically C# with where C-like language constructs were replaced with keywords.

Comment: @miroxlav - Yeah, just like a verbose deranged version of C# which renamed everything that most people consider industry standard into custom keywords. I wonder why its not popular. There is a reason it is in the hated list along with Objective-C (who *also* went the renaming NS-route).

Comment: @TravisJ – "deranged" is a strong word and I believe it comes mainly from one's mindset: If someone knows only C-like languages, then yes, everything else looks awkward. Even the SQL. Last 30 years I created programs in 40+ programming languages and I think that VB syntax is well and logically designed and is very readable. From long-time perspective, languages which unnecessarily encode things into symbols are no better in readability I believe it is rather emotionality about the whole thing (as you did show) than rationality what is keeping the people away.

Comment: @miroxlav As someone who's worked professionally with VB development (VB.NET, VB6 and VBA), I think "deranged" is an understatement. It probably does not come from some mindset, but from long-term use of VB. Including: different array indexing from file to file. The string parsing functions. The operators overall. I could write essays of how deranged the language is. There is absolutely zero reason to pick VB over C# or Java. If the verbose keywords are appealing, there's always Object Pascal... which ironically has always co-existed with VB and has always been better in every single way.

Comment: The _only_ advantage VB _ever_ had over any other existing language, was that some Microsoft lobby has been backing it.

Comment: Let's not make this a discussion about how (in)sane VB.Net is. The only sensible reply imo here is the first one: the index might be inaccurate. If VB.Net truly was the 5th most popular language removing it from the options probably wasn't a good choice, but [in 2018](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#technology) it was 6.7% indicating TIOBE probably doesn't reflect the SO audience. That still made removing it peculiar, considering most less popular and all more popular languages stayed an option in 2019.

Comment: @ErikA That discussion is highly relevant since VB has held the position as #1 most dreaded programming language for many years. Now it isn't. And so the whole most dreaded section has gone inaccurate and inconsistent with all previous years.

Comment: I agree, @miroxlav.  I've worked professionally in .NET since the v1 beta, using C# initially, then mostly VB, but still C# where clients require it.  Obviously, people with C or Java backgrounds are used to C# syntax - but intellisense and auto-complete mostly resolve the need to type verbosely in VB; Option Strict makes it properly type-safe.  Keywords eg End For, End While etc make code much more naturally readable than '}' as a block terminator for everything.  It also seems to me that still having semi-colons to terminate lines is bizarre in a 21st century language.

Comment: @ChrisA Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Lundin – VB.NET and C# are on par (1:1). It is just different syntax. There are even free tools to translate between them forth and back. Please don't confuse VB.NET with VBA and VB6. Yes, those are obsolete in every aspect, but not VB.NET. It is fun if I can openly say that many years, VB.NET was better equipped by language means than Java (lambda expressions, string interpolation, tons of goodies). My fellow Java programmers do not believe until I show them.

Comment: @TT. I made two opinion-based comments, namely the one about readability, and the one about the bizarreness of having to use ; and } to terminate lines.  Less than half the comment, so not primarily.

What is not an opinion is that unless the start of the block is visible in the code window, you can't tell from the '}' what sort of block it is.    Especially if there are consecutive ones.  You can get used to it, but (IMO), that inherently detracts from readability.

But obvs, 'real' programmers will never give up their love of C syntax :)

Answer (score 25):

VB.NET indeed was missing in the option list for the developer survey.

This was discussed quickly after the survey went live, but I think that discussion got deleted.

There was an option to manually type in a language, but that's different, of course.

Comment: Yes, the post I have posted about "VB.Net is missing in the survey" has been deleted. This is not very ethic from StackOverflow ! This survey has been intentionnally oriented. This year I don't read it. The probe is that C# is under VB.Net in TIOBE index !

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, this makes the survey inconsistent with previous years, where VB6/VB.NET has always held the #1 spot as the most dreaded programming language. A survey where VB *isn't* the most dreaded language, seriously?

Only VBA, Cobol and CoffeeScript have been close to challenging VB's leading position, but the latter two seem to also be missing this year.

So now VBA has stepped up to claim the throne, which probably isn't accurate - it might have been stealing votes from VB6/VB.NET.

Comment: I wonder how many of those that never used VBA and VB/VB.NET separately are even able to tell the difference between them.